# Xbox Live avatar with PC app

Tags: c#, xna, windows-8, avatar

I wonder if I could load `Xbox Live avatar` model into my `XNA` project?

I found some information that this is impossible in `PC` apps. But why? If I can use it in `WP7` and `Xbox` apps, so why I couldn't here?

Comment: Since Windows 8 will have much better Xbox LIVE integration you might be able to do it applications for Windws 8. I´ve tried using information from Xbox LIVE before, but accessing user´s achievements and such requires special licenses that you simply can´t get as a hobby programmer.

Comment: Hmmm, glad to hear it. My app is being designed for `Windows 8`. I guess that I need to wait for `XNA 4.5`?:/

Comment: Don't hope for XNA 4.5. You should check out Monogame (open source XNA) https://github.com/mono/MonoGame

Comment: Ohh, it should help. Thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the Xbox Live Avatar API is not exposed to projects that are not running on top of the Xbox Live ecosystem.

Your options as an independent app is to use avatar URLs to get a static image of it:

- http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/GAMERTAG/avatarpic-s.png
- http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/GAMERTAG/avatarpic-l.png
- http://avatar.xboxlive.com/avatar/GAMERTAG/avatar-body.png

Comment: Yes, I know about a static image, but I need the model of user's avatar to connect it into my Kinect application:/

Comment: You can't do that without being an XBL-approved developer.